# $ax+by+cz=d$. Find the lowest possible value for $x+y+z$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

If we have the following equation:
$$
ax+by+cz=d
$$
and it's said that:

- all the numbers are natural numbers
- $a,b,c,d$ are given

How can we find $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z$ is the lowest possible value?

Comment: You may want to make some assumptions such $a,b,c,d \ge 0$.

Comment: OP did say they're natural numbers, which covers that.

Comment: Do your natural numbers include zero?

Comment: @mvw yes, it does

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$$
ax+by+cz=d
$$
with real $u = (x,y,z)$ models an affine plane in $\mathbb{R}$.

If you restrict to whole numbers, the intersection with the grid $\mathbb{Z}^3$ will remain.

You can further restrict to the first octant, if $x_i \ge 0$.

The plane has a normal vector $n = (a,b,c)^\top$ and distance $d/\lVert n \rVert$ to the origin.

Your problem can be reformulated as integer linear program
$$
\min \{ c^\top u \mid A^\top u = d, u \in \mathbb{Z}^3, u \ge 0 \} 
$$
for $c^\top = (1,1,1)$ and $A = n^\top$.

You could also try solution methods for linear Diophantine equations (which give integer solutions) and then restrict to natural number solutions.

Another method seems combinatorial thinking.

Comment: I agree with you. but how can I calculate the coefficients of $u$?!

Comment: You can use an ILP solver, like I did in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2140904/86776. If you provide an example set of $a,b,c,d$ I can do a computation run for you.

Comment: the thing is that what I really want is to create the algorithm to compute these things haha. The a,b,c,d was just an example. What I need is $\sum_i^k a_ix_i = d$, where $min(\sum_i^k x_i)$. In the case for this question I considered $k=3$ and $a_1=a$,$a_2=b$,$a_3=c$. Got it?

Comment: Sure, grab any good book on integer linear programming or elementary number theory (linear Diophantine equations etc). If efficiency (say $O(n^3)$) is not a concern, you can simply bruteforce the solution, by checking a suitable part of the first octant.