# Why don't Lagrange multipliers work for this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I wanted to try this problem: [$ax+by+cz=d$. Find the lowest possible value for $x+y+z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273167/axbycz-d-find-the-lowest-possible-value-for-xyz)

So I wanted to try Lagrange multipliers.

Minimize $f(x,y,z) = x+y+z$ subject to constraint $g(x,y,z) = ax + by + cz = d$.

Then $\triangledown f =  \langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle$ and $\triangledown g = \langle a, b, c \rangle$. The equations to be solved are:

$1 = a \lambda $

$1 = b \lambda $

$1 = c \lambda $

$ax + by + cz = d$

Then $a = b = c = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}$ and

$\dfrac{x}{\lambda} + \dfrac{y}{\lambda} + \dfrac{z}{\lambda} = d$, or $\lambda = \dfrac{x+y+z}{d}$

But where do I go from here? Aren't I supposed to get $\lambda$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$? How can I do that when the $x,y,z$ terms disappear as a result of taking the derivatives of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: $\{a,b,c\}$ aren't variables here (I assume).  If you don't have $a=b=c$ then there is no solution.  Take, say, $(a,b,c)=(1,-1,1)$.  And $d=0$.    Then you can have the solutions $(x,y,z)=(-10^n, -10^n, 0)$ and we see that there is no minimum for $x+y+z$.

Comment: I believe $a,b,c,d$ are known / fixed and $x, y, z$ are variable. And probably positive values for everything too (no $0$s)

Comment: Well, if you have additional constraints then of course the answer changes.

Answer (score 2):

The method is working fine.  If $a=b=c$ ($=\lambda\neq 0$, say) then your constraint is $$\lambda(x+y+z)=d\implies x+y+z=\frac d{\lambda}$$  So every point on the constraint surface is a minimum (and a maximum).

If you don't have $a=b=c$ then the method correctly shows that a minimum does not exist.  For example, suppose the constraint is $$x-y+z=0$$  then $(x,y,z)=(N,N,0)$ is a solution for any $N$ and we can make $x+y+z=2N$ as small (or as large) as we desire.

Comment: I am new to Lagrange multipliers (trying to learn them at least); your expression seems a little different from mine though. I have $\lambda = \dfrac{x+y+z}{d}$ not $\lambda = \dfrac{d}{x+y+z}$. Did I set up my equations incorrectly? And how do you know every point is a minimum and a maximum just by looking at that piece?

Comment: Your $\lambda$ is not the same as mine (mine is the reciprocal of yours).  You correctly argue that if you have a min then $a=b=c=\frac 1{\lambda}$.  I just relabel the variable.  And in that expression we get that $x+y+z$ is a constant, so of course it is both a max and a min.

Comment: I should add:  I just looked at the problem you link to and in that case the variables were all required to be natural numbers.  That's a very different problem, not readily attacked by analytic methods like Lagrange.

Comment: @SeanHill The geometry of the situation supports the conclusions reached algebraically. The objective function is the dot product with $(1,1,1)$ and the points are on an arbitrary plane. When $a=b=c$, $(1,1,1)$ is normal to the plane and the dot product is constant. Otherwise, it can take on any value.